# Node.js application in IBM Bluemix gives 503 errors when live edit is used

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

IBM Devops provides the option of live-edit mode for applications hosted on Bluemix. Once enabled my node.js application failed with 503 errors, but the status of the application seemed fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On checking further, found that this was a known issue when Live Edit feature is used against an application running using the Node 4.x runtime on IBM Bluemix.

One way to get around this is by using 'cf' command line tool to push the application with Live Edit disabled initially and then manually enable Live Edit by using the 'cf set-env' command.

At First push the app, ensuring that the "BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE" variable is not set:

```
$ cf unset-env appName BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE
$ cf push appName
```

Then enable Live Edit mode manually using the environment variable, and restart the app:

```
$ cf set-env appName BLUEMIX_APP_MGMT_ENABLE=devconsole+inspector+shell
$ cf restart appName
```

This should help getting the live edit working for Node.js applications.

Comment: Also, ensure that you app is all lowercase.  There's a known issue when CamelCase is used for the app name.